# How to correct namespace for renderText in nested shiny modules?

Tags: r, shiny

I cannot find a way to use an output's variable in `renderText` in a nested UI module.

The problem came when I tried to grab the name of the tab and put it in the header title of my navbarPage layout.

I could not find a fix to my issue in the answers explaining how to deal with `renderUI(xxInput())` via `session$ns` [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38513912/shiny-using-uioutput-inside-a-module-or-a-nested-module). As `renderText` doesn't have an `id` argument, I don't know if this would apply anyway.

Minimal example:

```
library(shiny)

header_module <- function(id, label="My Header") {
  ns <- NS(id)
  headerPanel(
    div(
      h2("Some text", shiny::br()),
      #h2(textOutput("tab-name")),
      h2(textOutput(ns("tab-name"))),
      h2("Some more static text")
    )
  )
}

ui <- function(id, label="Main UI") {
  ns <- NS(id)
  navbarPage(title = "My app", 
             tabPanel(title = "My tab 1", 
                      pageWithSidebar(
                        header_module(ns("header")),
                        sidebarPanel(h2("Sidebar")),
                        mainPanel(h2("Main Panel"),
                                  textOutput("tab-name"))),
                      value = "Tab1"),
             id = ns("active-tab"))
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output[["tab-name"]] <- renderText({ input[["mainUI-active-tab"]] })

}

shinyApp(ui=ui("mainUI"),server=server)
```

[image]

The reference to the "active-tab" works in the main panel, not in the module-created header. If I use `textOutput(ns("tab-name"))` (like above), only an empty div is created `<div id="mainUI-header-tab-name" class="shiny-text-output shiny-bound-output"></div>`. If I use `textOutput("tab-name")`, the main panel goes empty as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the problem in your code doesn't have to do anything with modules. Here is a fixed version:

```
library(shiny)

header_module <- function(id, label="My Header") {
  ns <- NS(id)
  headerPanel(
    div(
      h2("Some text", shiny::br()),
      h2(textOutput("tab-name2")),
      #h2(textOutput(ns("tab-name2"))),
      h2("Some more static text")
    )
  )
}

ui <- function(id, label="Main UI") {
  ns <- NS(id)
  navbarPage(title = "My app", 
             tabPanel(title = "My tab 1", 
                      pageWithSidebar(
                        header_module(ns("header")),
                        sidebarPanel(h2("Sidebar")),
                        mainPanel(h2("Main Panel"),
                                  textOutput("tab-name"))),
                      value = "Tab1"),
             id = ns("active-tab"))
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output[["tab-name"]] <- renderText({ input[["mainUI-active-tab"]] })
  output[["tab-name2"]] <- renderText({ input[["mainUI-active-tab"]] })

}

shinyApp(ui=ui("mainUI"),server=server)
```

The issue was that the output-ID `tab-name` appeared twice in the UI which is not valid in HTML documents and therefore [not valid in shiny](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/743). Things get more complicated of course if outputs are defined within modules.

**Remark**: I would avoid IDs containing a minus symbol like `tab-name`, since `-` is used as a seperator for modules already. Also, the syntax `output$tab-name` will throw errors like `object "name" not found`.

Comment: Turns out I actually tried to keep only one `textOutput` but only while keeping the `ns("tab-name")` in `headerPanel` which doesn't work (no `ns` needed). Thanks a lot for your answer and additional explanations, it worked!